# Are there any FTP servers for Windows that can automatically backup files when they are replaced by new uploads?

Tags: windows, software-rec, ftp

I am looking for an FTP server running under Windows.

It should have a function that if the client uploads a file that already exists, the server can copy the old one somewhere as a backup. Any suggestions?

Comment: Thinks for Gareth's edition, and sorry for my poor English. :)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? I think you are going about it the wrong way.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into a versioning control system (git, svn) and/or using windows task scheduler (create a task triggered by an event).

Have you tried using this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_data_protection ?

Comment: also, how big are the files?

Answer (score 1):

I searched in the Internet, and found that there were some FTP server softwares could be configured to run a script when something happend. they are:

- [Sysax Multi Server](http://www.sysax.com/server/)
- [zFTPServer](http://www.zftpserver.com/)

With some work on configuration and script, the function could be achieved. I adopted Sysax Multi Server, since zFTPServer's script function only be supported by non-free version.